# SQL precompiled statements

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have an sql query like this.

`select * from table where owner='b' value=? and chanel='5'`

I will be searching always with owner b and chanel 5 only, does it make sense to keep it as place holder like below.

`select * from table where owner=? and value=? and chanel=?`

Does it improve performance or does it have any advantage?

Adam.

Comment: I think that the difference to process the other two parameter will be so little that it won't matter at all. At the end the cost for process this is the process of two prepared statement more. At the java side. for the database the query itself would be ready. Regard applications I would recommend you to choose the second one because today your scope is to search only `owner b and chanel 5` what if tomorrow someone ask you to change that? You wouldn't have to change your code, prepare your package and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle can use the extra information in the first question, so potentially it can do a better job optimising it.

Will it will make a noticable difference? Depends on your data and your indexes.
In most cases there will be no noticable difference, or the first will be slightly faster.

In some particular situations (especially if the statistics aren't up to date) the first form could perform worse. (For an example see [Oracle SQL: additional restriction causes performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655213/oracle-sql-additional-restriction-causes-performance-issues))

Answer (score 0):

I think the performance benefits will be negligable but the security benefits of using placeholders can be significant. The real performance inprovements will come from re-using the [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) (instead of creating one per query).

Consider the case where 'b' and '5' come from the user (eg request parameters in a web application). If you created the string using string concatenation, you open your application to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Using placeholders secures your app against SQL Injection attacks.

This cartoon explains the problem well: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements do improve performance, but only if you're going to use the same query multiple times in your project.

But it also brings advantages like avoiding SQL Injection, and allowing you to concentrate everything that is database-specific into a database managerment class. In the event of changing from Oracle to something else, you will only have to change one class in your code.

This same database managerment class can initialize all prepared statements when your program startup so they will be ready whenever you need it later, gaining performance.

[Here is an exemple](https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore/blob/master/src/server/shared/Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase.cpp) of an open source project that uses this model. It's C++, but may give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Some advantages to using literals:

1. **Avoid weird optimizer limitations and bugs.**  This is the main reason to use literals when you can.  Oracle can use [adaptive cursor sharing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_cursor.htm#TGSQL94740) to build different plans for the same SQL statement, depending on the values of the bind variables.  Building plans that change based on bind values is difficult, and there are many limitations and bugs.  For example, it only supports up to 14 bind variables and does not support `LIKE` predicates.  It might cause problems if one of your not-really-bind-variables disabled this feature for the real bind variables.
2. **Statements are easier to read.**  Especially for a DBA who views the statement from V$SQL.  Adding the bind information to the query is extra work, and sometimes that data is not available.  And it may make explain plans easier to generate and read.  For example, with a literal the explain plan may show the exact partitions being used.  With a bind variable, it may only show `KEY`, which won't make it as clear which
3. **Small performance improvement.**  I don't know exactly how the optimizer works, but it's a safe bet that it must store bind variables and look them up to compare values used for existing plans.  Avoiding those lookups should help, although the difference will probably be very small.

The obvious disadvantages to literals, that you've probably already considered:

1. Possible SQL injection if you're just plugging in data straight from a user.
2. Not as flexible if you want to change your code later.